# Continuous functions and existence of a root

Tags: analysis, functions, proof-verification, continuity

Let $\, f:[1,2] \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that for every $n$ $\in$ $\mathbb N, \exists$ $x \in [1,2]$ with $\ |f(x)| < \frac 1n$

Show that $ \exists \;c \in [1,2]$ such that $ \;f(c)=0$

So with this, I went by contradiction and said that (I'm being informal here) that if f(x) doesn't equal to 0 then the function completely lies on one side of the x axis then argued by Archimedes Principle saying there's a number with 1/n < c (where c is the absolute min of the function in [1,2], which exists by Boundedness Property) leading to a contradiction.

Is this an acceptable way to go about this proof?

Comment: You also need to argue why f attains a minimum/maximum.

Comment: @OohAah As it is a continues function over a bounded interval, it has a minimum and maximum

Comment: @AMIR The comment was directed at the OP's proof sketch.

Comment: @AMIR Just to be picky, $1/x$ is a function on the bounded interval $(0,1)$ that fails to attain its max. Of course in the OP's case we have a function on a *compact* interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_n\in[1,2]$ such that $|f(x_n)|<1/n$. Then, by the squeezing theorem,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=0
$$
because
$$
-\frac{1}{n}<f(x_n)<\frac{1}{n}.
$$
Since $[1,2]$ is compact, the sequence $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ and if $x=\lim_{k\to\infty}x_{n_k}$, then
$$
f(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_{n_k})=0
$$
by continuity.

---

Your idea is good as well. If $f(x)\ne0$ for all $x\in[1,2]$, then we can assume $f(x)>0$ (or consider $-f$, otherwise). Thus the minimum $f(c)$ of $f$ in $[1,2]$ is positive. But there exists $x$ with $f(x)<1/n$ and we can choose $n$ such that $1/n<c$. Contradiction.